# Updating Layer tree after changing symbology with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, legend, layertree

When I change symbology for a given `QgsVectorLayer` (QGIS 2.14.16 LTR) by

```
r=iface.activeLayer().rendererV2()
r.symbol().symbolLayers()[0].setColor(0,0,255,255)
```

as shown here:

[image]

and refreshing the map content by

```
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

I get the expected result, but the Layer Tree does not update as shown here:

[image]

What am I missing, and how can I update the Layer tree from PyQGIS programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell the layer tree view to refresh your layer's symbology:

```
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology( iface.activeLayer().id() )
```

Comment: iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(lay) 
where lay is the QgsMapLayer object which symbology changed.

Comment: @AndreasMüller According to [the docs](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsLayerTreeView.html#a65b2ace23d214e9d4ca5c70964d00e3d), you need to pass the layer id, not the layer object.

Comment: http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsLegendInterface.html#aa09d4d2c66c2b82fac04f593db833def it's the layer object if using legendInterface, not very consistent...

Comment: Ah! But remember that legendInterface is legacy code. Layer tree classes are always recommended.

Comment: Oh, i used this often, can't find a hint that it is legacy code...

Comment: For instance, legendInterface won't be available in QGIS 3.0: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/doc/api_break.dox#L277